# Jquery ajax Pass post back data to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have the below script to generate days in month with jq, I want to get the post back data pass to `for` loop as condition in php so that it could populate days in selection box accurately.

Here is how change the days based on year and month

```
$('#mm').change(function () {
    var mm = $(this).val();
    var yy = $('#yy').val(); //get the year
    var dd = days_in_month(mm, yy);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/callback/req_days_in_month.php',
        data: {
            days: dd,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //something to do to pass data to php...?
        }
    });

    $('#dd').val(dd);
});
```

I want `$i<=31` replace with postback value from ajax,

```
<select id="dd">
for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){
    echo '<option value="$i">$i</option>';
}
</select>
```

**req_days_in_month.php:**

```
<?php
    $days = $_POST['days'];
    echo $days;
?>
```

Can it possible be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need some ajax calls to do this.

```
$('#mm').change(function(){
var mm = $(this).val();
var yy = $('#yy').val(); //get the year
var dd = days_in_month(mm,yy);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/callback/req_days_in_month.php',
    data: { days: dd, },
    success: function(data){
        //something to do to pass data to php...?
    }
 });

    $('#dd').val(dd);
});
```

because `var dd = days_in_month(mm,yy);` can get the no. of days.

do something like

```
$('#mm').change(function(){
var mm = $(this).val();
var yy = $('#yy').val(); //get the year
var dd = days_in_month(mm,yy);

var options = "";
for(var i = 1; i <= dd; i++){
    options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}
$('#dd').html(options);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/callback/req_days_in_month.php',
       // data: { days: dd, }, change in
      data: { days: dd }, // remove comma  
        success: function(data){
            //something to do to pass data to php...?
        }
    });
```

reference **[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you got the number of days in the javascript itself, why would you want to make a ajax request and get the same result? Anyway you can do like this,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/callback/req_days_in_month.php',
        data: { days: dd },
        success: function(data){
            //something to do to pass data to php...?
            var days = data;
            var html = '';
            for(i=1;i<=days;i++)
            {
                html += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
            }
            $('#id').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'inc/callback/req_days_in_month.php',
        data: { days: dd }, // remove comma after dd  
        success: function(data){
            //something to do to pass data to php...?
            var days = data;
            var html = '';
            for(i=1;i<=days;i++)
            {
                html += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
            }
            $('#id').html(html);
        }
    });
```